# Lower bound on the individualization set for $k$-iso-regular graphs ( degree at max three )?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, isomorphism-testing

Assume graphs of degree at most three for this question.

A graph is said to be k-isoregular if for every subset $S$ of at most $k$ vertices the number common neighbors of the elements of $S$ depends only on the isomorphism type of the subgraph induced by $S$.
 The $k$-dimensional  Weisfeiler Lehman fails on  $k$-iso-regular regular graphs. $k$ is a constant here, definitely if $k = O(n)$ then $k$-dimensional  Weisfeiler Lehman will work correctly.

Suppose I bound the maximum degree of the input graph to three, then also there are graphs on which $k$-dimensional  Weisfeiler Lehman fails. So one possible way to deal this situation is **individualization** along with $k$-dimensional  Weisfeiler Lehman.

Small example of an iso-regular graph:

[image]

**Question :** Is there any known claim on the size of individualization set for $k$-iso-regular graphs ( degree at max three )? Is constant size individualization set possible? 
I tried to search on google scholar, but did not get anything specific.

Comment: How is the number of neighbours of a $k$-tuple defined?

Comment: @  Brendan McKay It is not just number of neighbours, but number of common neighbours. I have edited the question

Comment: The example seems to be 1-iso-regular but not 2-iso-regular.  Otherwise I don't understand the definition.  Please give a non-trivial example of a 2-iso-regular graph with maximum degree 3.  Frankly I am doubting their existence (except for some tiny graphs).

Comment: @ Brendan McKay  This is 4-iso-regular

Comment: I down-voted.  Several days after Aaron told your that your definition of $k$-iso-regular makes no sense, you still didn't fix it. Under your definition, every graph is $k$-iso-regular when $k$ is greater than the maximum degree, and it is not true that $k$-iso-regular implies $k-1$-iso-regular. I'll also note that the definition in Douglas' paper is different from the definition in his reference [11] that he claims to get it from.

Comment: @Brendan McKay I have edited the question and given the definition of $k$-iso-regular.

Comment: The set $\lbrace 4,5\rbrace$ and the set $\lbrace 4,14\rbrace$ both induce an empty subgraph.  But 4,5 have one common neighbour and 4,14 have none.  So your graph isn't $k$-isoregular for $k\ge 2$.  Actually, as Aaron says, 2-isoregular is the same as strongly regular.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for results in the literature you need to be sure you are using a definition that others use. Do you have a reference for your definition of $k$-iso-regular? The definition I am familiar with is that for any set of **up to** $k$ vertices the number of common neighbors depends only on the isomorphism type of the induced graph on those vertices so:

Every vertex has the same number of neighbors (aka regular) AND the number of common neighbors of two vertices $u,v$ depends only if $uv$ is or is not an edge (aka strongly regular) AND the number of common neighbors of $u,v,w$ depends on the isomorphism type ($4$ cases) of the induced graph on $u,v,w$ etc up to $k$ vertex sets.

**also** For graphs of bounded degree ,GI is decidable in polynomial time.

Comment: I have seen this definition here.See page no-5 , second paragraph https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.5211.pdf

Comment: That definition says every $k$-element set **of a certain isomorphism type** . Although they don't say it explicitly, it is also clear that the condition applies to sets of size up to $k$ since it says $5$-iso-regular implies $t$-iso-regular$ for all $t$.

Comment: OK but your graph above is not $2$-isoregular so also not $k$-isoregular for $k=3,4.$ I'm sure that constant size would not be enough. In the event that the graphs **are** $2$-isoregular (hence diameter $2$) it is known that $\sqrt{n}\log{n}$ vertices suffice. If a constant size was possible in general that wouldn't be a very good result.

Comment: Please provide a reference for the result ($\sqrt n \ log n$) (is it for at most degree 3 graphs ?)

Comment: My starting point was that your definition of isoregular was not useful for the question. I would look at this article and papers which reference it for more helpful information and bounds https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/papers/13focs-SRG.pdf

Comment: A $k$-isoregular graph is also $2-$isoregular which means diameter $2$ and there are no vertices at distance $4$. Whatever you want to do for max degree 3, isoregular isn’t going to be relevant.